# What is probability 4 people were all born in four different seasons? Same season?

Tags: probability

My answer would be:
(1)

1st person: 1

2nd person: 3/4

3rd person: 2/4

4th person: 1/4

Multiplying, we get:
P[Four people born in four different season] = 0.09375

(2)

1st person: 1

2nd person: 1/4

3rd person: 1/4

4th person: 1/4

Multiplying, we get:

P[Four people born in the same season] = 0.015625

I am doubting if my answer is correct??

Comment: Seems correct.${}$

Comment: 4 choices for birth season of 1st person; 3 choices for 2nd; 2 choices for 3rd; 1 choice for 4th. In total, $4\times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 4!$ choices. Without any constraints, there are $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 4^4$ choices for the seasons of all four persons. Therefore the probability you seek is $p=4!/4^4 = \ldots = 6 / 64 = 0.09375$.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Comment: Assuming birthdays equally distributed over the four seasons, which seems not to be realistic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influence_of_seasonal_birth_in_humans

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct on both.

There are $4!$ choices for all $4$ people to be born in different seasons, and since each person has $4$ seasons they could be born in, the probability is $\frac{4!}{4^4} = 0.09375$, as you got.

And in the same season, it doesn't matter what the first person gets, but each of the second, third, and fourth people need to be the same as the first, which is probability $\frac{1}{4}$. So the total probability is $\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{4} = 0.015625.$